# Reasoning over `exactly` and `some ` clause

Tags: logic, owl, ontology, protege, reasoning

This is regarding the inference made on the `Result` class on the below ontology. Right now the reasoner is running with `Goal` being defined equivalent to `Goal and fulfilledBy only Requirement` which does not classify it. When the axiom is changed as `Goal and fulfilledBy some Requirement`, the classification is done although there are no relations from `Goal1` to anything else. Could someone help in clarifying this? `

```
<!-- 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Object Properties
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 -->




<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/Test/ontologies/2018/4/untitled-ontology-91#fulfilledBy -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/Test/ontologies/2018/4/untitled-ontology-91#fulfilledBy"/>



<!-- 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Classes
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 -->




<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/Test/ontologies/2018/4/untitled-ontology-91#Goal -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/Test/ontologies/2018/4/untitled-ontology-91#Goal"/>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/Test/ontologies/2018/4/untitled-ontology-91#Goal1 -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/Test/ontologies/2018/4/untitled-ontology-91#Goal1">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/Test/ontologies/2018/4/untitled-ontology-91#Goal"/>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/Test/ontologies/2018/4/untitled-ontology-91#fulfilledBy"/>
            <owl:qualifiedCardinality rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#nonNegativeInteger">1</owl:qualifiedCardinality>
            <owl:onClass rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/Test/ontologies/2018/4/untitled-ontology-91#Req1"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/Test/ontologies/2018/4/untitled-ontology-91#Req1 -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/Test/ontologies/2018/4/untitled-ontology-91#Req1">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/Test/ontologies/2018/4/untitled-ontology-91#Requirement"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/Test/ontologies/2018/4/untitled-ontology-91#Requirement -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/Test/ontologies/2018/4/untitled-ontology-91#Requirement"/>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/Test/ontologies/2018/4/untitled-ontology-91#Result -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/Test/ontologies/2018/4/untitled-ontology-91#Result">
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Class>
            <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/Test/ontologies/2018/4/untitled-ontology-91#Goal"/>
                <owl:Restriction>
                    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/Test/ontologies/2018/4/untitled-ontology-91#fulfilledBy"/>
                    <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/Test/ontologies/2018/4/untitled-ontology-91#Requirement"/>
                </owl:Restriction>
            </owl:intersectionOf>
        </owl:Class>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
</owl:Class>
```

`

Comment: Asked and answered here several times. OWL -> [Open World Assumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-world_assumption)

Comment: It's also not clear what you mean by the "classification is done" - which inferred axiom are you talking about?

Comment: okay. I meant the `only` clause.  I was thinking, if there is an axiom with an `exactly` clause, it is considered by the reasoner as a closed world, which will get classified by the `only` .

Comment: I don't get it. Can you clarify based on your example what exactly you think would be inferred?

Comment: By the way, `exactly` also lacks from the OWA given that for a class expression `(= 1 p.C)` there might be more (but unknown) relations with the property `p`

Comment: Okay, I guess that's what I was looking for. What i meant was that the reasoner could correctly classify Goal1 into the Result when `some` was used and not with `only` which was opposite to my understanding with the axioms created with `exactly`. Hope it clarifies